# How to Run Script on Multiple Spreadsheet Tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

how do you run a script on multiple tabs in one google spreadsheet file.

each sheet has the same layout and I need it to proform the same action. But I can not work out how to make work on different tabs. I am new to this so all help would be much appreciated

```
function autoSort(){
 
const ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Wit")
const range = ws.getRange(3,2,ws.getLastRow()-2,16)
 
range.sort({column:16,ascending:true})
 
 
}
 
function onEdit(e){
 
  const row = e.range.getRow()
  const column = e.range.getColumn()
 
  if(!(column >= 9 && row >= 3)) return
autoSort ()
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const names = ['Wit', 'Sheet2','Sheet3',....];//add sheet names
  const idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart < 9 && e.range.rowStart < 3) {
    sh.getRange(3, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 2, 11).sort({ column: 16, ascending: true })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this I will try it out and let you know. Thanks so much